# Reopen: Struggling in my first software development job, how to decide if I should move on?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Struggling in my first software development job, how to decide if I should move on?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/69701/2322)

This question was just closed. I think it's a valid question:

- It is now asking for how to process through the decision (not what to do)
- This is a situation that a *lot* of people face
- Getting insight into the  "how should I think about whether to leave or not" question is very different than "should I leave this job" question

If not, what needs to change to the wording to make it on topic?

---

**EDIT**: The question was reopened on 2016-06-14 14:10:15Z.

Answer (score 7):

I'm for reopen.

It is a situation nearly everyone in IT faces at one point or another, and was closed mostly by non-IT people.

Add to that, the plethora of good advice in the answers, this deserves to be reopened.

Comment: I just cast a 5th reopen vote (it had 4, so mine counted as a single vote) on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was one of the close-voters, and since some people consider the close-voters to be jerks, I will post an answer here.

My close vote was for the [original version of the question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/69701/1), and I still stand by my close vote. While [I have empathy for the OP](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/69701/struggling-in-my-first-software-development-job-how-to-decide-if-i-should-move#comment192330_69701), the question was off-topic as far as this site is concerned since it asked for advice on whether OP should move on.

The question has since been edited to "how should I decide whether to move on?", but that is just shoehorning an on-topic question. It is easy enough to apply the same shoehorning to make *any* "seeking advice on what to do" question on-topic.

Specifically, perhaps the most common theme of questions closed as off-topic for this reason involve "which job should I take?". Just edit the question to "how should I decide which job to take?", and it becomes on-topic. This sets a bad precedent.

Next up is the argument about the situation being very common in IT. With all due respect, choosing between multiple job offers or deciding whether to take a job or not is *more* common (and not just in IT). It is only fair that such questions be allowed too.

It doesn't concern me much if the question is reopened, but unless the "amnesty" is extended to all "seeking advice" questions, be prepared for some troublesome discussions in future, of the type, "how come *my* question was closed, but *that* question is allowed?" :)

Comment: Are you sure we're talking about the same post?  This one is not about a job offer, but someone walking into a situation where they have to learn fast and are feeling like an imposter.  Nobody has, to my knowledge called anyone a jerk, yet.  As for precedents, nobody needs one to whine as that precedent has been set long ago.  IT is a fairly unique field in many ways as it is constantly shifting and changing.  Quite frankly, a mechanic, for example, isn't having HIS tools changing every ten minutes or being told to work on a type of vehicle that didn't exist five years ago.

Comment: @RichardU A mechanic might be a bad example, as with electronics dominating the car market right now they are forced to change tools quite often compared to a decade ago. A better example would be a carpenter, workbenches today vary only slightly from those used centuries ago.

Comment: @Reaces my brother is an aircraft mechanic, even his field hasn't changed as much as mine, not by several orders of magnitude

Comment: @RichardU Which makes sense, aircraft have a much longer life-cycle than cars. And there are a lot fewer models, and fewer people who service multiple models. When you said mechanic I immediately thought car mechanic.

Comment: @Reaces neither have changed that much in 50 years, where we've gone from vacuum tubes to microchips, to the internet with integrated technology.

Comment: @RichardU Hmm, interesting. I posted 2 links in my answer which lead to that question, and you still have doubts whether I am referring to the same question? I know what the situation is, but nonetheless, the question is still, "should I continue this job or should I quit?". Shoehorning a "how should I decide?" doesn't change anything, IMHO. The point about "which job to take" was just to emphasise why such shoehorning sets a bad precedent. Anyway, it is not the goal of my life to keep that question closed. If you guys want to reopen it, then do so.

Comment: @MaskedMan Sorry.  I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the wording should Change as I feel this question, after looking into the reversions.
Has been closed for a valid reason, It is simply off-topic.

I feel that the following is to vage in this case:

> Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do.

While regardless how we Change the qeustion, we would still give advice on what to do, but because we look at it from the why how Point it is suddenly on-topic.

That being said:

> If not, what needs to change to the wording to make it on topic?

I would Change it into the Options the op is willing to take instead of asking for advice.
That are questions which we can answer why or how you should take them.

Since I thought about this I didn't close vote this myself, because I felt it to be an gray Zone in our on-topic specifications.